# how to appending write audio frame use ffmpeg ？

Tags: ffmpeg

- I found that ffmpeg has a concat protocol that can be used to splice/merge multiple audio files, but it has a param ouput file, that is, a new production to a target file; But I want to have a pattern added to the source file, just like the behavior of the fopen when mode = "a": Appends to a file. Writing operations. End of the file.
- Is there a direct way to do this?

  FILE *fopen (const char *filename, const char *mode)

Comment: FFmpeg can't typically write to the file that it's reading.  This wouldn't work for most formats anyway.

Comment: This file is not opened by any process, now I just want to open and add new frames to the end of the file

Comment: Sure, but you can't, is what I'm telling you.  You would have to specify that file as an input.  If it were just a normal MPEG-TS file or something you could literally just concatenate, but most formats you cannot.

Comment: @Brad *FFmpeg can't typically write* --> "typically" : do you know of a counterexample*? *except for very tiny files which ffmpeg manages to read fully before opening output for writing.